# Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
import React , { Component } from 'react'

class Login extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <form className="login-form">
                <h1>login</h1>
                <div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label for="name">
                            Name :
                        </label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label for="password">
                            Password :
                        </label>
                        <input name="password" type="Password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the issue is here,

```
//input is an empty tag and you have provided Submit as children here
<input type="submit">Submit</input>
```

It should be simply this,

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 3):

ravibagul91's answer is correct. `input` is self-closing element. You cannot have children in it.

Alternatively, you may use button:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

To this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```